# No sound on Facebook Gameroom for unity WebGL

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl, facebook-gameroom

We have a game build for WebGL, using WebAssembly.

Everything is working well, on all newer browsers (even Edge version 41).

The problem is when the game is played in Facebook Gameroom, **all sounds stopped working**.

We do not create a gameroom build, since gameroom can run WebGL content, and everything was ok up until several days ago.

We assume there was an update in Gameroom, but not sure.

Anyone else got this problem?

Comment: Same problem since facebook gameroom 1.20, I use unity for all sfx sounds and no sound at all. I also use a third party library to play music : https://howlerjs.com/ and same problem -> no music. I hope facebook team will make a patch quickly !

Answer (score 0):

Since I was having this problem as well, I've done a little research on google and facebook and many people claimed they have this problem. It seems like it appeared with the most recent version of the application because everyone posted comments since yesterday.

Comment: Opened a bug on Facebook for this one:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/341162109702515/